# Substrings and Subsequences

Tags: string, combinatorics

In a string of length n, how many Sub-strings and Sub-sequences can I have... even tho a sub-string is obtained by deleting any prefix and any suffix from s, while a sub-sequence is any string formed by deleting zero or more not necessary a consecutive positions of s.

Comment: Im studying compiler , so I just need the general formal form for it ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not ignoring duplicates:

**sub strings = n(n+1)/2**


  count the number of 1 length sub strings = n 

  count the number of 2 length sub strings = n-1

  count the number of 3 length sub strings = n-2

  ....

  count the number of n length sub strings =  n - (n-1) = 1

generalizes to the sum of the sequence of numbers from 1 to n.

**sub sequences = 2^n**

Think of the string as a bit array. either include the character in your sub sequence or do not. there are 2^n combinations.

Comment: as a sub-string, a string of length 1 has only one sub-string , while length 2 has 3, length 3 has 6, 4 has 10, 5 has 15 and 6 has 21.. I can find no relation between them ..

Comment: @user3419748 I have edited my answer to include an explaination.

Comment: is "empty" is considered as a valid sequence ??

Comment: @user3419748 It depends on your specific application.